# Storing Android app data locally. Alternatives to the Room Library

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a messenger app.  And for correct work with the backend, it is proposed to cache data after the first launch. In the future, it is only necessary to update existing data.
At first I thought of storing data using `AndroidX Room`.  However, after a few tests, I realized that it has a rather long data update operation, while the delete operation is very cheap.
The behavior of my application means that the most frequent operation will be updating existing data.  Are there faster alternatives to the Room library?

Comment: https://realm.io/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47219257/7874746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, use [ObjectBox](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java) instead of Room. it is a NoSQL Java database built for storing data locally, offline first on resource-restricted devices like phones.

Being NoSQL means it is faster in CRUD operation than other SQL ones.